# Issues with Target Path in powershell in creating a short cut

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a short cut on public desktop for users, but this target path for this short cut is causing some issues.

```powershell
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.shell

$desktop = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("desktop")

$lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortcut("$desktop\CLMCPDEDEV.lnk")

$lnk.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Unisys\WebEnabler\Web Enabler.exe" "configfile=c:\development-installs\web-enabler-config\CLMCPDEDEV.cfg"
```

I have the config file in another folder and exe is in a different path. I'm new to power shell, how do I bypass that space  between `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Unisys\WebEnabler\Web Enabler.exe"` and `"configfile=c:\development-installs\web-enabler-config\CLMCPDEDEV.cfg"`?  That's the full short cut path when I do this manually. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Does putting a single quote before `"C:` and after `.cfg"` help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [CreateShortcut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys.aspx) method documentation:

> A common problem is putting arguments in the TargetPath property of
>   the shortcut object, which doesn't work. All arguments to the shortcut
>   must be put in the Arguments property.

So you have to do this:

```powershell
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.shell

$desktop = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

$lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortcut((Join-Path -Path $desktop -ChildPath 'CLMCPDEDEV.lnk'))

$lnk.TargetPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Unisys\WebEnabler\Web Enabler.exe'
$lnk.Arguments = 'configfile=c:\development-installs\web-enabler-config\CLMCPDEDEV.cfg'

$lnk.Save()
```

Comment: That worked and to move the short cut to public I used the typical cmd /c xcopy %userprofile%\desktop\CLMCPDEDEV.lnk c:\users\public\desktop
and then cmd /c del %userprofile%\desktop\CLMCPDEDEV.lnk to avoid duplicate icons

Comment: Hi BeatCracker. What command would I use if I want to change the short cut icon to the specific lnk above in the public desktop?  I have a ICO file in a folder that is a different color that I want clmcpdedev.lnk to use?

Comment: Actually when changing the icons for shortcut on one machine and using a script to delete the original icons then copying the new icons  to the target machine, the icons stay for awhile and then break and become generic. Do I have to use iconlocation argument?

Comment: @joextreme: you can specify the icon location with `$lnk.IconLocation = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Unisys\WebEnabler\web enabler.ico',0`
(assuming this is the icon file location) The "0" argument means specify the icon in the first position, which is required for non-embedded icon definitions.
BTW, this post finally fixed my problem with creating a link.  The magic stuff here is the `$lnk.Arguments` which I was missing when specifying `cmd /K "...."` command